# How to start a method with a button click

Tags: android

I am trying to start a method by clicking a button. The idea, and please tell me if there is a better way, is to put all the code for some calculations into a method called calculateratios. Then once the button is clicked it will run through some if statements to check and see if some of the textfields are empty. if none are empty then it runs the method calculateratios. Otherwise display a toast saying "Enter all data". I have the following java.

Java File

```
package com.th3ramr0d.poundforpound;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button calculate;
Button reset;

EditText inputname1;
EditText inputname2;
EditText inputbodyweight1;
EditText inputweightlifted1;
EditText inputbodyweight2;
EditText inputweightlifted2;


TextView outputname1;
TextView outputname2;
TextView outputratio1;
TextView outputratio2;
TextView finaloutput;

double inputbodyweight1var = 0;
double inputweightlifted1var = 0;
double inputbodyweight2var = 0;
double inputweightlifted2var = 0;
double ratio1 = 0;
double ratio2 = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    reset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);

    inputname1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputname1);
    inputname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputname2);
    inputbodyweight1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputbodyweight1);
    inputweightlifted1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputweightlifted1);
    inputbodyweight2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputbodyweight2);
    inputweightlifted2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputweightlifted2);

    outputname1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputname1);
    outputname2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputname2);
    outputratio1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputratio1);
    outputratio2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.outputratio2);
    finaloutput = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.finaloutput);


    reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            inputname1.setText("");
            inputname2.setText("");
            inputbodyweight1.setText("");
            inputbodyweight2.setText("");
            inputweightlifted1.setText("");
            inputweightlifted2.setText("");
            outputname1.setText("");
            outputname2.setText("");
            outputratio1.setText("");
            outputratio2.setText("");
            finaloutput.setText("");

        }

    }
    );

//
//
//ThIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CLICK MY BUTTON TO CHECK IF STATEMENTS
//
//
    calculate.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                calculateratios();


                }
            }
    );

}

//THIS IS THE METHOD I WANT TO RUN IF THE IFSTATEMENTS ALLOW IT

public void caculateratios(){
    String inputname1var = inputname1.getText().toString();
    String inputname2var = inputname2.getText().toString();

    inputbodyweight1var = Integer.parseInt(inputbodyweight1.getText().toString());
    inputweightlifted1var = Integer.parseInt(inputweightlifted1.getText().toString());
    inputbodyweight2var = Integer.parseInt(inputbodyweight2.getText().toString());
    inputweightlifted2var = Integer.parseInt(inputweightlifted2.getText().toString());


    double ratio1 = inputweightlifted1var / inputbodyweight1var;
    double ratio2 = inputweightlifted2var / inputbodyweight2var;

    outputname1.setText(inputname1var);
    outputname2.setText(inputname2var);

    outputratio1.setText(String.format("%.2f" + ": 1", ratio1));
    outputratio2.setText(String.format("%.2f" + ": 1", ratio2));

    if (ratio1 > ratio2){
        double strengthdif = ratio2 / ratio1;
        strengthdif = (1 - strengthdif) * 100;
        finaloutput.setText(inputname1var + " is stronger than " + inputname2var + " by " + (String.format("%.2f", strengthdif)) + "%");
    }
    else{
        double strengthdif = ratio1 / ratio2;
        strengthdif = (1 - strengthdif) * 100;

        finaloutput.setText(inputname2var + " is stronger than " + inputname1var + " by " + (String.format("%.2f", strengthdif)) + "%");
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

The problem is that I am unsure of how to do this method. When I set it up like it is above the calculateratios() called in the onClick is red and the logcat says:

Error:(87, 21) error: cannot find symbol method calculateratios()

Any help on how to set this up properly? Thanks!

Comment: why do you have a ; at the and of your caculateratios method?

Answer (score 3):

You have an extra semicolon (**;**) at the end of `calculateratios()` (which is also **misspelled**).
Remove it.
And adjust the method name.

Answer (score 3):

The method name you are invoking in your button click method does not match the method name you are trying to invoke... To be honest I don't know how your code compiles if you are using an IDE. Change your onClick to the following:

```
calculate.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            //OLD:   calculateratios();
            /*NEW:*/ caculateratios();
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: i have shamed myself with a typo =(